# Async Pipe in Template not rendering data

Tags: angular, angular5

I am recieving data from a promise on bootstrap and assigning it to an object within the service. Within a component I am retrieving that object on NgOninit and Assigning it to an observable. My template has the async pipe, however from the component when I log the value it prints out fine, but within the template it is showing up as null?

```
    private legal = new Subject();
    public legal$ = Observable.from(this.legal);

    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.title.setTitle('Legal Agreement');
    this.submitted = this._stepService.submitted;
    this.checkBox.nativeElement.checked = this.submitted;
    let legal = this._legalService.legalDocument;
    // Subscribe to the local provider error service
    this.errors$ = this._errorService.error$;

    this.errors$.subscribe(value => console.log('Error is --> ', value));
    this.legal$.subscribe((value: any) => console.log("legal is: ",value));

    // Set the Errors and Responses to the subjects accordingly for broadcasting
    this.legal.next(legal);
    this.test = this._legalService.legalDocument.legal;

}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="(legal$ | async); else other_content">
  <html-outlet [html]='legal$.legal'></html-outlet>
</div>

<ng-template #other_content>other content here...</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 2):

#### In these kind of scenarios we want `Behaviour Subject`

**Solution**

```
private legal: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
```

**TO Check it's working [Click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so)**

#### Behaviour Subject

BehaviourSubject will return the initial value or the current value on Subscription

#### Subject

Subject does't hold any values and returns only the current value on Subscription.

[Read more](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<div *ngIf="(legal$ | async) as templegal; else other_content">
<html-outlet [html]='templegal.legal'></html-outlet>
</div>

<ng-template #other_content>other content here...</ng-template>
```

Comment: Didn't work, if I call the service within my component then it works. But since this service is called on bootstrap of the application, and then that respones object is stored in a service variable. It doesn't work... Trying to make work without calling service in component. If I subscribe to the observable legal$ within my component it prints out the value, but in the template showing as null.